# Nodejs Callback Function

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi I'm trying ping a port from nodejs. I use tcp-ping module. I want return available value from tcp.probe function. But i cant. 
Here is my code

```
var tcpp = require('tcp-ping');
function ping_port(callback){
tcpp.probe('10.5.177.52', 8080, function(err, available) {

    return_value = available;
    callback(available);
});
    }
function read() {
    console.log("Read done")
  return return_value;
 }
module.exports.ping = function()
{
    var port_status = ping_port(read);
    console.log(port_status);
    return port_status;

}
```

I resolved my problem by waiting for return_value varrible not equals undefined.Here is my code.

```
var tcpp = require('tcp-ping');
var return_value;

module.exports.ping = async function(page,ip)
{
   tcpp.probe(ip, 8080, function(err, available) {
    return_value = available;
}); 
 while(return_value === undefined)
 await page.waitFor(100);
 return return_value;
}
```

The page is a puppeteer modules function. I call `await foo.ping('page' , 'ip')` from my main async function and its done.
I'm sorry about my bad English and coding. I'm beginner in coding.

Comment: use a Promise and async/await, it could help you

Answer (score 1):

You can't return a value from an async function. Instead, make the user of the module pass a callback to the ping function.

```
module.exports.ping = function(callback)
{
 ping_port(callback);
}
```

Use it like this:

```
function foo(port_status) {
    console.log("This is the port status: " + port_status);
}

const ping = require('./your_module');
ping(foo);
```

Comment: I try that code but i want use port_status value outside function foo and ping_port. I call ping(foo) in an async function.